# Determining major mode for proper comment character insertion

Tags: init-file, major-mode

I currently have a function like so in my `.emacs` file:

`(defun insert-todo ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "// TODO(map) : ")
  )`

It is bound to my key combination of `"C-t"`.  This will work for me if I'm doing Java or JavaScript code as the `//` is the start of a comment for that particular language.  However, I want to dynamically insert the appropriate comment character based on the major mode I'm in.

For example:

`Java Mode -> //
Python mode -> #
Lisp mode -> ;;
etc...`

So how do I, in my `.emacs` config file, get the current major mode so I can insert the appropriate comment characters before adding my TODO string?

Comment: You're reinventing `newcomment.el` which provides functionality for language-agnostic commentary.

Comment: Does that package allow for extending the functionality to include extra information in the comment?  So not just deciding on which type of characters are used for commenting?

Comment: It gives you all the comment-related commands, including one to comment out a region. So, insert text, comment out the region and you're done.

Comment: So that's not exactly what I want.  It's great that I can type text and then comment it out, but the goal is basically to bind a key that auto inserts my `TODO(map)` as that is what I do searches on in my code before commits.

Comment: Yes, this is done programmatically. It's extremely common to change the location of point, insert text into a buffer and call other functions manipulating buffer text. Rejecting an approach on this basis would mean rejecting lots of packages.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly major-modes are setting `comment-start` and `comment-end`. Below an example how to access these values:

```
(defun give-me-comment-starters-ender-for-a-mode (mode)
  "Returns a cons containing comment-start comment-end of arg MODE"
  (with-temp-buffer
    (funcall mode)
    (cons comment-start comment-end)))

(defun comment-starter-ender-return-test (&optional arg)
  (interactive)
  (let ((erg (give-me-comment-starters-ender-for-a-mode (or arg 'emacs-lisp-mode))))
    (message "%s" erg)))
```